# Text enclosed in html tags in API request for no reason, can I do something about it?

Tags: json, api

I want to use AutoPilot's API to get the CRM tasks with it but it returns some data incorrectly. Some parts of the respone are correct like:

```
[
  {
    "event_id": "1111",
    "event_title": "something",
    "event_desc": "description of the event",
    "event_start": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "event_end": "2016-02-25 00:10:00",
    "event_location": "",
    "event_status": "1",
    "event_category": "category",
    "created_by_username": "worker01",
    "assigned_userid": "1111",
    "contact_email": "email@email.com",
    "customfields": null
  },
```

but others have HTML tags in it

```
{
    "event_id": "2222",
    "event_title": "titletitle",
    "event_desc": "<p>description<\/p>\n",
    "event_start": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "event_end": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "event_location": "",
    "event_status": "1",
    "event_category": "category",
    "created_by_username": "worker2",
    "assigned_userid": "222",
    "contact_email": "mail@mail.com",
    "customfields": null
  },
```

See the description? I don't know why some of them are enclosed in HTML tags...some are even worse like:

```
"event_desc": "<table style=\"box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); ba... etc
```

The API should return normal texts, I asked AutoPilot but they aren't really helpful...

Comment: If it's an existent API, probably is not your fault. Have you think to make a filter (when you get the data for example) which remove all the html tags? For example, in PHP there is an predefined function strip_tags() that does what I said.  I could may help you better

Comment: presumably they're like that because that's what someone input into that field. And presumably the system allows HTML input, perhaps it uses it to format the description within a GUI. So it seems perfectly reasonable. If you don't want it, you'll have to parse it as HTML and discard the tags.